# what's the best way to automate post-build actions?

Tags: maven, maven-2, build-automation, luntbuild

We use Luntbuild to do our builds. Our project builders are in Maven 2.  After each build is done we need to do a lot of cd, mkdir, cp, unzip rm and zip commands. We currently have a shell scrip that does this but we need to wait for a successful build and then manually run that script.  Is there a way to set luntbuild to do the post-build actions for us as soon as it gets a successful build.
If so what should the format of the post-build script be? and how do i set it up?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to run your script via the maven invoker plugin. There is also [an example on their site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html).